# How do you store quantities of items in an SQL database? (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to think of the most straightforward way to store quantities of an item in a database. I'm creating a database to work in conjunction with a web app I'm developing to monitor and log gear lent out to people. So, I've thought a few different ways already, though I'm not sure if they will be easy to maintain into the future.

**Idea 1**

I have a `gear` table that stores the types of gear (e.g. shirt, pants, hat) along with data like sizes etc. Then for each time gear is taken out, it is logged in the `gear_inventory` table, storing details such as user id, gear type and boolean to signify if it was returned and return date. Then to track quantities, we'll have total_quantiy and count of gear out for a specific gear item in the `gear` table, this being updated manual with a second query triggered when an item is taken out or returned to plus or minus the given quantity.

**Idea 2**

Have the aforementioned total quantity out linked to the `gear_inventory` as a count of all non-returned items of that type.

**Idea 3**

Have an update task to change these quantities on table update or insert. Then do the same by adding or subtracting the quantity of a given query.

Idea 1 would be the easiest but not as reliable as the others. Idea 2 being the most reliable the handling of quantities is entering on the database to ensure. Then Idea 3 not as reliable since it's still relying on a scheduled task to update it.

So, how would you implement a quantity amount to ensure it doesn't get out of sync with the logged inventory records?

**Edit 1**

More info - The core solution I am trying to achive is having a method of storing or having a count of items taken out which can be compared to a total nunber associates with that item. As suggeated below, it will act in a similar fashsion to a bowling alley's loaning/borrowing shoes, exect users will be logged. So a record will be inserted when an item is borrrowed, and that record will be updated with return date on return. The types of items will be in its own table to store details on a general item, and that will have a one to many relationship with the logged gear table. The problem is, what is a full proof/reliable way to store/retrieve number of items out. Or am I overthinking this and a simple count query would sufice, not sure how intensive count is when performed oved and over again.

Comment: If you could talk more about the problem you're trying to solve and less about your proposed solutions, this will be easier to answer. It seems like it will be handled by some straight-forward join tables, but it's hard to figure out the parameters of the problem. What's the scenario? What will you want to do with the data? Is this like a bowling alley renting out equipment?

Comment: @Schwern Added more info, hopefully thats what you were looking for.

Comment: I think that idea 2 is best, since you won't likely work with big data and don't need statistics table. You could create additional table called `gear_inventory_returned` and move records from `gear_inventory` to said table and this way get much smaller and easier set to count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think about what we're keeping track of.

- Information about kinds of items.
- Current inventory.

  - Which item?
  - How many?
- What's been loaned out.

  - To whom?
  - Which items?
  - How many?
- What's been returned.

  - By whom?
  - Which items?
  - How many?

First cut might look something like this:

```
create table items (
    id serial,
    name text,
    ...
);

create table inventory (
    id serial,
    item integer references items(id),
    quantity integer check(quantity >= 0)
);

create table loans (
    id serial,
    user integer references users(id),
    item integer references items(id),
    quantity integer check(quantity >= 0),
    when_loaned timestamp not null default now(),
    when_returned timestamp
);
```

When you loan something out, insert a row into loans. When its returned, set loans.when_returned. If loans.when_returned is null, it's still out.

You could decrement the inventory when items are loaned, and increment it when they're returned. To preserve data integrity this should be done as a trigger, *not* as a scheduled process.

Alternatively, *don't* change the inventory quantities. Instead, subtract the number of loaned items from the amount in inventory. That's `select sum(quantity) from loans where item = ? and when_returned is null` from `select quantity from inventory where item = ?`. This makes loans and returns simpler, and avoids the possibility of the inventory count being corrupted, but it might cost performance problems if there's many, many outstanding loans.

---

What happens if you loan out 5 items and they return 3? How do you track that? One simple option is to split a single loan into two loans.

```
-- Copy the loan row
insert into loans
select * from loans where id = :orig_id

-- Track that 3 were returned
update loans
set quantity = 3, returned = now()
where id = :orig_id

-- Two are now outstanding
update loans
set quantity = 2
where id = :new_id
```

Without knowing more about what you're using this for, what the use cases are, and what the scale is, that's about all I can say. It's a good starting point.